# Providing CRM 2011 functionalities via Web Services

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

A partner provided me with a series of functionalities he would like to have in the CRM 2011 Web Services.

None of them is really difficult to write, but I cannot figure out how the Web Services capabilities could be extended.

An example of a method implementation I should write is here:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetUnitConversions">
    <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISales/GetUnitConversions"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header message="tns:ServiceHeader" use="literal" part="Header"/>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:header message="tns:ServiceHeader" use="literal" part="Header"/>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Is there some file in the CRM server that should be modified? Is that supported by Microsoft?
Any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real way to "extend" the Microsoft Web Services itself. It's a fixed framework that provides a fixed set of web services and methods.

For CRM Online The only way you could provide something like this is by extending the platform and what's available to you on that front. The main areas that are "code" based and I would believe might be of significance to you are:

- Plugins
- Custom Workflow Activities
- HTML/Javascript/Silverlight Web Resources

Some of these need to be backed of Entities (e.g. Plugins), but others can stand alone and just do some generic work (e.g. HTML and Silverlight pages)

So basically, if they require a standard set of "functions" added to the framework you'd have to get inventive using the above methods to provide this for them.

If it's on-premise then you could probably write an external service that in turn knows how to authenticate and perform the actions against CRM.

**Updated answer to cover updated question:**

There's definitely no supported way to extend the Microsofts provided webservices. And there's no way I know of to even do it unsupported without physically hacking their DLLs.

The supported way is use one of the methods above. To give you an example of a supported way that would allow you to implement the above method:

- Create an entity called "WebServiceCall"
- Create 2 attributes on this: "Method" and "Result"
- Create a synchronous plugin in the on PreCreate of this entity
- When the plugin fires it reads the Method, executes the relevant code, and sets the result.

To execute a method called "GetUnitConversions" all you have to do is:

- Create a new record of type WebServiceCall and set the method to "GetUnitConversions"
- When this finishes it will return the id of the record created
- Retrieve the entity using the id and read the result.

That's as close as you're going to get to a solution which supports both Crm Online and OnPremise

Comment: That's a good answer, but I will need something a little more specific. I have updated my question.

Comment: Updated answer to give more detail and an example

Comment: I don't need to support CRM Online. does that make a difference?

Comment: It's not going to make much of a difference for something like this. Another way you could implement this is provide your own external Web Service implementation that hooks into CRM using the standard API. Then the partner would have to use your webservices instead of the CRM ones. But if you go down the plugin route it will be more contained, and cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I hade the same thought. But how would it be possible to handle parameters?

Comment: Simplest way to handle it is add another attribute to the entity (WebServiceCall) named "parameters". You could pass it in as an XML string and parse it on the client side. Or, even simpler, a comma/pipe delimited string if that would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need in this situation is a service BUS, like BizTalk, that serves as the middle man for these sort of required message formats.  Send a request in whatever format you'd like to the BUS, the BUS knows how to route it to what ever system is in the request, and how to translate the request from the sent format, into a format the receiving system understands.

In your sort of request, there is no reason you have to create a plugin.  Create a receiving webservice (ideally a BUS) to receive the message, and the use the CRM SDK to determine the result.

Comment: Being able to call CRM Webservices would make things way easier for the partner, plus BizTalk does not ship for free.

Comment: Why do they care?  If they want to specify what the request message format is, you'll need a "man in the middle" because as @ConorGallagher suggests, there is no way of specifying a different format for the SOAP messages of the CRM SDK.

Comment: As Daryl suggests here this is the "write an external service" option I spoke of. It really depends if you need it "contained" within CRM or not. Keeping it within the realms of CRM so that they don't have to use any external web services means utilizing plugins etc. Or if you want to extend the CRM model write a "man in the middle" service like this to relay all messages on to CRM.